# Mobile SDK: ActiveTrack Mission for reaching specified point of the Concrete wall

Tags: dji-sdk

I wonder I can use DJI 'Mobile SDK: ActiveTrack Mission API' not for targetting moving objects but for reaching specified point of the Concrete wall.

If Concrete wall is too homogeneous to identify,I consider light up the destination point with laser pointer to specify.

Can I use  Mobile SDK : ActiveTrack Mission for such purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way ActiveTrack I am certain it will not satisfy your requirements.

ActiveTrack tracks a "moving" object, if you point to the object (aka, wall) then the camera and aircraft may identify and follow the wall but until the wall moves the aircraft will hover in-place (same as it does when you start with a human target).